# What happens when the result of the shift operation does not fit in the type of the left operand?

Tags: solidity, data-types, solidity-0.8.x, bit-manipulation

For instance, take the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

function foo() external pure returns (uint256, uint256, uint256) {
    uint256 i1 = uint256(2) << 255;
    uint256 i2 = uint256(4) << 255;
    uint256 i3 = uint256(8) << 255;
    return (i1, i2, i3);
}
```

In a purely mathematical sense, the result should be `(2**256, 2**257, 2**258)`. But these numbers overflow the maximum value permitted by `uint256`, which is `2**256 - 1`.

What does Solidity do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/types.html?highlight=shift#shifts), Solidity truncates the result:

> The result of a shift operation has the type of the left operand, truncating the result to match the type.

So in the example above, the first bit, two bits and three bits, respectively, get truncated. The actual result is `(0, 0, 0)`.

This can be more clearly seen if you remove the casting around 2, 4 or 8. The compiler would complain with the following error:

[image: Solidity complaining about literal too large]